# Trying to get property of non-object when accessing from called function

Tags: php, yii

I'm using yii framework but I think this is related to PHP

In my controller,  I have the following code

```
$model = new Events;
    $model->type_id = $type_id;
    $checkFileUpload = checkFileUpload($model);
```

the function checkFileUpload is a custom function which contains

```
function checkFileUpload($model)
    {
        $rnd = rand(0, 9999);
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        if($uploadedFile->error == 0)
        { 
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number  file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
...
```

I got the error get property of non-object in $uploadedFile->error.

I've tried to use reference to the model instead, but it is deprecated and does not work for me.

If I use the code of the called function (checkFileUpload)  within the controller code, it works fine. I suspect that object is not passed in a correct way.

Any help?

Comment: What version of Yii - 2 or 1?

Comment: @u_mulder version 1.18

Answer (score 0):

This is because your call to `CUploadedFile::getInstance` returns `null` and not the instance you desired.

> Null is returned if no file is uploaded for the specified model attribute.
>
> — [Yii Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstance-detail)

It seems like your file was not correctly uploaded. I am not a Yii Framework user, but the documentation states:

> The file should be uploaded using [CHtml::activeFileField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeFileField).
>
> — [Yii Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstance-detail)

So you should verify that the file was actually correctly uploaded with the proper method from the Yii Framework.

PS: Objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: how do you explain that it works when the code is within the controller and does not work when code is in an external function?

Comment: Tried to bend my head over that as well. My answer is most certainly the correct answer to the problem, but I simply can't tell why it magically works if executed within the controller. I'd need to know more about the Yii Framework, of course about your additional code, and the test(s) you perform to verify the functionality. Maybe you can post more of the surrounding controller class and elaborate on how you test it? Although I can't guarantee that I'll be able to give an answer then.

Comment: I've put the function and call the function from within the controller. And I got the same error. You think that it related to the way yii.

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that the file upload failed. Might be that Yii failed to properly upload the file or PHP, or the server, or … that's hard to assess from such a remote point. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = new Events;
$type_id=$model->type_id;
$checkFileUpload = checkFileUpload($model);

    function checkFileUpload($model)
        {
            $rnd = rand(0, 9999);
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if(!isset($uploadedFile->getHasError()))
            { 
                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number  file name
                $model->image = $fileName;
```

Comment: checkFileUpload is an external function and I use require to include this function.  I call like this $checkFileUpload = checkFileUpload($model); which code do you want me to post?

Comment: The method call will fail as well, since `$uploadedFile` is `null` (see my answer). The `$model` does not have an uploaded file for the `image` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because at the time when you are using **$uploadedFile->error**,the value of **$uploadedFile** is `null`.

The following line is not giving you the desired value

**$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');**

Which means no file has been uploaded.

Try `CVarDumper::dump($_FILES,10,true);`

This will tell you whether the problem is with the `UPLOADING OF THE FILE` or `GETTING THE DETAILS OF THE UPLOADED FILE`

Answer (score 0):

you cant access the private property $_error `$uploadedFile->_error` if you are trying to. you must call `$uploadedFile->getError()` in your code. Also $uploadedFile will return null if no file uploaded so you must take care of that as well.

```
$rnd = rand(0, 9999);
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
        if(!empty($uploadedFile) && !$uploadedFile->getHasError())
        {
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number  file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
```

will work for you.